# How to detect when a Poco sub Process crashes?

Tags: c++, c++11, poco-libraries

I am using Poco to create a process in my app. I would like to relaunch the process if the process exits gracefully or it crashes.

Currently it is started as follows:

```
ProcessHandle ph = Process::launch( "foo.exe", args, 0, &outPipe, 0);
PipeInputStream istr(outPipe);
std::string s;
int c = istr.get();
while (c != -1)
{ 
    s += (char) c; c = istr.get(); 
}
```

Graceful exit is handled easily by waiting for the output pile to end as shown above.

How can I handle when the process crashes? I need to handle this on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

use the [wait()](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.ProcessHandle.html#9804) function of the `ProcessHandle` object in a different thread. when the wait() call returns, the process has terminated. usually processes that crash have a non-zero exit code, and the `wait()` call returns that exit code

Comment: Am replying after long time, but am facing same problem. I tried `wait()` but it is always returning `0` . Searched a lot but couldn't find a better way to track process in POCO. This is the reason I am discarding POCO for spawning and tracking a process. Now using `fork` and `exec` (for unix).